# How to automate moving two headers in a horizontal Ant Design step range slider using Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, slider, cypress, antd, e2e-testing

I have been trying to move the two headers of an Ant design step range slider using the cypress automation.

It was for selecting a salary range in our project, so to filter salaries based on the selected range we have to move the headers. So, I was trying to automate that scenario.

But it is not giving any successful output.

I was expecting to move the slider headers with their values and apply a range for the application.

I used the selectors of two headers and added below code snippet to move the headers, it seems the headers are selected but they are not moving.

```
changeSliderValues() {
    cy.get('#__next > div > main > nav > div.SearchComponents_searchPanel__PdBhP.no-horizontal-scrollbar > div > div.SearchComponents_searchFilterContainer__4XHi5 > div > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > ul > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ant-slider-handle.ant-slider-handle-1')    
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })  // Start dragging
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 1000, clientY: 0 })  // Move to the desired position
      .trigger('mouseup');  // Release the mouse button
  
    cy.wait(500);
  
    // Repeat for the second value
    cy.get('#__next > div > main > nav > div.SearchComponents_searchPanel__PdBhP.no-horizontal-scrollbar > div > div.SearchComponents_searchFilterContainer__4XHi5 > div > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > ul > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ant-slider-handle.ant-slider-handle-2')    
      .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1, force: true })
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 5000, clientY: 0 })
      .trigger('mouseup');

  }
```

Then again, I tried below method which select the track of the slider, but it only moves the right-side header for both.

```
changeSliderValues(newValue, newValue2) {
        cy.get('.ant-dropdown-menu > :nth-child(1) > .Filters_filterSalaryArea__GhohX > :nth-child(3) > .ant-space > :nth-child(1) > .ant-slider > .ant-slider-track')
          .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })  // Start dragging
          .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: newValue, clientY: 0 })  // Move to the desired position
          .trigger('mouseup');  // Release the mouse button
        
        cy.wait(500);
      
        cy.get('.ant-dropdown-menu > :nth-child(1) > .Filters_filterSalaryArea__GhohX > :nth-child(3) > .ant-space > :nth-child(1) > .ant-slider > .ant-slider-track')
          .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })  // Start dragging
          .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: newValue2, clientY: 0 })  // Move to the desired position
          .trigger('mouseup');  // Release the mouse button
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealmousedown) plugin to move the antd slider.

Here is a simple example using the antd demo page.

```js
cy.visit('https://ant.design/~demos/slider-demo-input-number');

// what is initial value
cy.get('.ant-input-number input').eq(0).should('have.value', 1)

cy.get('.ant-slider').eq(0)
  .realMouseDown()
  .realMouseMove(50,0)
  .realMouseUp()

// what is new value
cy.get('.ant-input-number input').eq(0).should('have.value', 3)
```